# Plotting predicted values in ARIMA time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

There are likely more than one serious misunderstandings in this question, but it is not meant to get the computations right, but rather to motivate the learning of time series with some focus in mind.

In trying to understand the application of time series, it seems as though de-trending the data makes predicting future values implausible. For instance, the `gtemp` time series from the `astsa` package looks like this:

[image]

The trend upward in the past decades needs to be factored in when plotting predicted future values.

However, to evaluate the time series fluctuations the data need to be converted into a stationary time series. If I model it as an ARIMA process with differencing (I guess this is carried out because of the middle `1` in `order = c(-, 1, -)`) as in:

```
require(tseries); require(astsa)
fit = arima(gtemp, order = c(4, 1, 1))
```

and then try to predict future values ($50$ years), I miss the upward trend component:

```
pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 50)
ts.plot(gtemp, pred$pred, lty = c(1,3), col=c(5,2))
```

[image]

Without necessarily touching on the actual optimization of the particular ARIMA parameters,  **how can I recover the upward trend in the predicted part of the plot?**

I suspect there is an OLS "hidden" somewhere, which would account for this non-stationarity?

I have come across the concept of `drift`, which can be incorporated into the `Arima()` function of the `forecast` package, rendering a plausible plot:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
fit1 = Arima(gtemp, order = c(4,1,1), 
             include.drift = T)
future = forecast(fit1, h = 50)
plot(future)
fit2 = Arima(gtemp, order = c(4,1,1), 
             include.drift = F)
future2 = forecast(fit2, h = 50)
plot(future2)
```

[image]

which is more opaque as to its computational process. I am aiming at some sort of understanding of how the trend is incorporated into the plot calculations. Is one of the problems that there no `drift` in `arima()` (lower case)?

---

In comparison, using the dataset `AirPassengers`, the predicted number of passengers beyond the endpoint of the dataset is plotted accounting for this upward trend:

[image]

The [code](http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/complete-tutorial-time-series-modeling/) is:

```
fit = arima(log(AirPassengers), c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))
pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 10*12)
ts.plot(AirPassengers,exp(pred$pred), log = "y", lty = c(1,3))
```

rendering a plot that makes sense.

Comment: I would say that if you think you have a series where the trend has changed over time, ARIMA models may not be the best way to approach prediction of them. In the absence of subject matter knowledge (which might lead to better models), I'd be inclined to look at state space models; in particular variants of the Basic Structural Model for something like this. Many discussions of state space models can be hard to follow, but Andrew Harvey's books and papers are quite readable (the book *Forecasting, Structural Time Series Models and the Kalman Filter* is pretty good, for example). ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... There are a few other authors that do reasonably well, but even the better ones make it a bit more complicated than it really needs to be for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b. Just trying to get a flair for time series, and as in many math topics the lack of motivating preamble is a killer. All time series that we may really care about seem to trend up or down - populations, GOP, stock market, global temperatures. And I get that you want to get rid of the trends (may be for a second) to see cyclic and seasonal patterns. But the splicing back of the findings with the overarching trend to make predictions is either implied or not addressed as an objective.

Comment: Rob Hyndman's comments [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/) are relevant. I may come back and expand on that a little.

Comment: Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Constants and ARIMA models in R"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimaconstants/) is probably all you need to know. I would be curious to hear you opinion once you explore the blog post.

Comment: Thank you. I am making some progress. It's a lot of fun!

Comment: Antoni, have you found what you were looking for, and could you perhaps even self-answer? In any case, I second @Glen_b's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229948/plotting-predicted-values-in-arima-time-series-in-r#comment435335_229948): if you have a *constant* trend, then the differencing in ARIMA makes sense; but if the trend *changes* over time, then something like a state space model or double exponential smoothing looks better. Global temperatures are a case of the latter, as are stock markets on a daily or lower scale.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I haven't gone back to explore time series in quite some time, and reviewing the OP, I have the impression I pretty much stuffed in there all the "tricks" I could come up with. I understand your comment (and Glen_b's) regarding non-linear trends.

Comment: The following paper provides the reasoning/logic underlying AUTOBOX's feature which can distinguish between deterministic trend and stochastic trend. The former employs level shift indicators and time trend predictor series series along with possible pulses and seasonal pulses AND arima structure. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y31HS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y31HS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why you shouldn't do ARIMA or anything on non stationary data.

Answer to a question why ARIMA forecast is getting flat is pretty obvious after looking at ARIMA equation and one of assumptions. This is simplified explanation, do not treat it as a math proof.

Let's consider AR(1) model, but that is true for any ARIMA(p,d,q).
Equation  of AR(1) is:
$$ y_t = \beta y_{t-1} + \alpha + \epsilon$$
and assumption about $ \beta $ is that $|\beta| \le 1$. With such a β every next point is closer to 0 than the previous until $ \beta y_{t-1} =0 $, and $y_t = const = \alpha $.

In that case, how to deal with such a data? You have to make it stationary by differentiation ($new.data=y_t-y_{t-1}$) or calculating % change ($new.data=y_t/y_{t-1} -1$). You are modeling differences, not a data itself. Differences are getting constant with time, that is your trend.

```
 require(tseries)
 require(forecast)
 require(astsa)
 dif<-diff(gtemp)
 fit = auto.arima(dif)
 pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 50)
 ts.plot(dif, pred$pred, lty = c(1,3), col=c(5,2))
 gtemp_pred<-gtemp[length(gtemp)]
 for(i in 1:length(pred$pred)){
   gtemp_pred[i+1]<-gtemp_pred[i]+pred$pred[i]
 }
 plot(c(gtemp,gtemp_pred),type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In a nutshell, $\alpha$ would be the slope of the final plot?

Comment: No. I think that you confused it, because the slope is often denoted as $\alpha$. However, if you would ask what is the relationship between this $\alpha$ and a slope, answer won't be trivial. In a nutshell, if you had chosen differentiation, $\alpha$ would be a tangent of a slope, if you had chosen % change there wouldn't be any slope, because trend won't be linear.

Comment: OK. I'll have to play a bit with your code see what it is trying to illustrate in relation to the ts equation. I haven't worked with ts, and it's been a while I since I posted the question.

Comment: After playing a bit with the code, I see what's going on. Can you include the coefficients of fit, which are `AR1 = 0.257; MA = - 0.7854`, into the ARIMA model equation to fully appreciate the generating process of the projected or predicted tail sloped line at the end of your plot?

Comment: Sure. In my answer I put only AR(1) equation. Equation for whole ARMA(p, q) process is $$\hat y_t = \sum^p_i \beta_i y_{t-i} + \sum^q_j \gamma_j\epsilon_{t-j} + \alpha+\epsilon_t$$ where first sum is AR(p) part and second sum is MA(q) process. We have here ARMA(1,1), so it is less complex: $$\hat y_t = \beta y_{t-1} +  \gamma\epsilon_{t-1} + \alpha+\epsilon_t$$
where $\beta =0.257$, $ \gamma =-0.7854$, $ \alpha=0.0064$.

Comment: In the case of the first value of `pred$pred[1]  -0.01755181`, do you know how it would be calculated using the `fit$coef[]` and perhaps the values of `gtemp[130]`?

Comment: I wasn't right in my previous comment. It seems that auto.arima function returns coefficients for different version of this equation. For ARIMA(1,0,1) equation is:$$(1-\beta O)y_t=c+(1+\gamma O)\epsilon_t $$ where $O$ is an operator such that $Ox_t=x_{t-1}$. $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the same, but it returns $c$ instead of $\alpha$, $\alpha=(1-\beta)c$, in our case $\alpha=(1-0.257)  0.0064= 0.0047552$.  
 
Hence, code for pred[1] is:  
`fit$coef[1] * dif[length(dif)] + fit$coef[2] * fit$residuals[length(fit$residuals)] + fit$coef[3]*(1-fit$coef[1])`

Comment: If you don't mind two additional follow-up questions: 1. How would the calculations proceed for `pred$pred[2]`? - In other words, past the point where there are no more prior `fit$residuals`? And 2. What is the source equation, or the explanation, for the last part of your code above, `fit$coef[3]*(1-fit$coef[1])`?

Comment: 1. Moving average part doesn't have impact on the model for predictions points bigger than moving average order, because as you mentioned there are not residuals available anymore.

Comment: 2. $$(1−\beta O)y_t=c+(1+\gamma O)\epsilon _t$$ I wrote that `auto.arima()` returns $c$, which is not right. They use this equation:
$$(1−\beta O)(y_t-\mu)=(1+\gamma O)\epsilon _t$$
$$(1−\beta O)(y_t)=(1−\beta O)\mu + (1+\gamma O)\epsilon _t$$
$O$ don't affect $\mu$, because it is not time dependent, so we have

$$y_t-\beta y_{t-1}=(1−\beta)\mu + \epsilon _t+\gamma \epsilon_{t-1}$$
$$y_t=\beta y_{t-1} +\gamma \epsilon_{t-1}+(1−\beta)\mu + \epsilon _t$$
auto.arima() returns $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\mu$ from this equation, hence our $\alpha$ is $(1−\beta)\mu$.

Comment: Do you happen to have any reference as to how the predicted tail of the graph could be "manually" calculated beyond the first point? The documentation of `predict()` seems to indicate that this is a difficult topic, yet the plot seems extremely linear.

Comment: ARIMA is usufull only for a few steps ahead prediction. As I wrote, it is getting flat because coefficients have to be lower than 1, everything except constant is going to 0 with n going to infinity. https://otexts.org/fpp2/arima-r.html this is site of Hyndman, he is the author R foceast package. You can find more details here.

Answer (score 0):

One popular reason to why predictions look that "linear" is because you may not have made it as stationary as it needs to be. I would check for seasonality etc. In other words, just because a ADF and KPSS test says the data is stationary it is worth while to inspect the data visually or think intuitively about the trend to make further adjustments before you predict it. This may avoid that upward "linear" trend look.